# Add a new column as Unique Constraint to table that has value EF 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to add a new column as Unique key where the table has already data.
I am using EF 6.0 and code first approach and I added the property [Index(IsUnique = true)] and generated the Migration Script but when executing I am getting an error as the column added is new and there is no value to it

Comment: 1. Add the column; 2. Set the data; 3. Add unique index

Comment: @Klamsi We can't define data setting in EF migration query I believe. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You shuld be able to edit the migration file

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
[Index("IX_FirstAndSecond", 2, IsUnique = true)]
public int SecondColumn { get; set; }
```